# How to show page and parent page's name on custom blog page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a page called "community", and selected it as Blog page from Settings > Reading in wordpress admin. Now this "community" page is working as blog.

I want to display parent page's name on top of the Community page.

i tried `$parent_title = get_the_title($page->post_parent);`

but it returns post title instead of parent page's title.

"Community" page is created under "About" page, i want to get "About" as a result.

This needs to be dynamic because administrator may change name of pages later.

Comment: Do you mean parent pages of the community page or pages that are parent to other pages? Sounds like you want to create a menu of pages.

Comment: I want to display name of parent page of community page.

Comment: Which template file are you editing?

Comment: I have created a custom template.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, here is the code i have used.

```
<?php
    $parents = get_post_ancestors( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
    $id = ($parents) ? $parents[count($parents)-1]: $post->ID;
    $parent = get_page( $id );
    $parent_title = $parent->post_title;
    echo $parent_title;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this i have added this code on my blog page to get the page title

```
   $page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );



         $page=(get_page( $page_for_posts ) );?>
//title
        <h1> <?php echo $page->post_title;?></h1> 
//parent Page title
         <h1><?php echo get_the_title($page->post_parent);?></h1>
```

Comment: This displays name of page itself, how can i get name of its parent page?

Comment: i have modified by answer try this